# Set value in app.config file to null

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, app-config

i'm updating an app.config value during runtime, I want to update the value to a null value but so far I just get an empty string. I still want to be able to set the empty string for another purpose, but how do I get that value to return null?

Comment: what if you remove the <value/>?

Comment: @Hybridzz can that be done programmatically?

Comment: try AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key)?

Comment: @Hybridzz of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the key, if you remove it then the value will be null.

```
var val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]
```

you can remove the key in code

```
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
 config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("key");
```